# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}nu_{n}=A>0$ the series $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}$ diverges

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}nu_{n}=A>0$ the series $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}$ diverges.

The proof is:

"*If $u_n >\frac{A}{n}$ then $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}$ diverges since the  harmonic series diverges*".

I may be mistaken but can't it also be true that $u_{n}<\frac{A}{n}$, in which case the comparison test wouldn't apply?

Comment: The proof seems slightly off; but eventually, $u_n > A/(2n)$, which is enough to show divergence.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for clearing that up. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is a little bit off, but you can prove using the Limit Comparison test: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot u_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{u_n}{\frac{1}{n}}=A>0.$$ So, by the limit comparison test, both series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n}$ and $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}}$ converge or both diverge. Now, since you know that the harmonic series diverges, you can conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ also diverges.